# Failing hard drive or bad controller after hard shutdown

Tags: linux, sata, smart, bad-sectors, hard-drive-failure

After nouveau freezing everything with dual monitor for the millionth time I had to cut power on my macbook pro (mid 2010, fedora 24, SAMSUNG HN-M500MBB hard drive). Wasn't doing anything IO heavy just viewing slides with evince.

At reboot it starts spitting out errors about a bad sector and hanging with errors like:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 969158669
ata1: EH complete
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3c000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:d0:08:30:c4/00:00:39:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq dma 4096 in
         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/28:d8:c8:2f:c4/00:00:39:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq dma 20480 in
         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/38:e0:88:2f:c4/00:00:39:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq dma 28672 in
         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/78:e8:08:2f:c4/00:00:39:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq dma 61440 in
         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1: hard resetting link
ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
```

with the occasional

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 39 c4 30 08 00 00 08 00
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 969158669
Buffer I/O error on dev dm-2, logical block 1, async page read
```

and

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata1.00: failed command: READ SECTOR(S) EXT
ata1.00: cmd 24/00:01:0d:30:c4/00:00:39:00:00/e0 tag 6 pio 512 in
         res 51/40:01:0d:30:c4/00:00:39:00:00/e0 Emask 0x9 (media error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { UNC }
```

Here's smartctl output after trying to read a couple of sectors after the bad one with hdparm:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       469
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   086   086   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       4463
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8099
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19382
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       980
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8214
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       66246139
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3820
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   064   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 15/49)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       255
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       980
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1583719
```

Note the pending sectors... Both short and long self tests report the same bad sector as the kernel.

Hdparm <s>oddly manages to read everything successfully but it</s>(*see the edit below*)  kind of hangs and says

```
reading sector 969158769: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0a 00 51 e0 01 11 04 00 00 a0 71 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
succeeded
```

And it says it for something like 200 sectors after the first bad one.
I rewrote a couple of ones with hdparm --write-sector and they stopped complaining. Now I'm doing a backup and ordered a new drive, but meanwhile I'd like to understand what happened and maybe try to fix this one.

Note the reallocated sector count is not being increased after I rewrote a couple of bad ones, which adds up to the weirdness of the whole thing. After a rewrite they read and write fine like nothing happened but the firmware doesn't seem to remap them as bad sectors.

Any idea? Should I just ditch the drive?

PS. OSX in another partition still works pretty fine.

---

**EDIT: aftermath**

After a backup I started experimenting a bit with the hard drive.

After the first bad sector there were about another 150 with the same issues. I tried reading them with `dd` and `dd_rescue` and they failed.
`hdparm --read-sector` worked (with the sense error above) but returned inconsistent data (different at each read).
`hdparm --write-sector` seemed to fix them so I just rewrote all the failing sectors.

Now `smartctl` reports 0 pending sectors and 0 reallocations, both short and long self tests complete without errors. Linux boots fine, all the errors vanished.

I'm a bit worried about those ~70kb I killed, it's a bit tricky with LVM to understand what they really contained. I dumped a couple of MBs around that area and it's all zeros, so I'm positive it's either empty space or swap.

Too soon to celebrate yet, but the outcome looks promising, will update the question if anything new happens.

Comment: The odd thing is that you get a *timeout* error instead of just a "bad sector" error. So my guess would be that the internal microcontroller gets confused somehow, possibly because the reallocation map is inconsistent (or because other things are inconsistent). Writing the sector and forcing reallocation may make the map more consistent as it's modified. But that's all a blind guess.

Comment: An interesting experiment would be to zero the drive completely after making a backup, either directly by writing or with a "SECURITY ERASE" if the HDD supports it, and see if that fixes it, because the internal state should then be renewed.

Comment: Ok, now that I have a backup I'll do some experiment. The first thing I'd like to try is to rewrite the "bad" sectors. Given hdparm can read the data, do you know if I can rewrite the same data it reads instead of zeros?

Comment: I'd use `dd` or `dd_rescue` for that instead of `hdparm` (which AFAIK can only write zeroes).

Comment: I'd use them too... unfortunately hdparm is the only one who manages to read anything from those blocks :-(

Comment: Pardon, it reads garbage apparently, two subsequent reads give different results on the same sector. The first returns non zero data, then every new read returns all zeros.

Comment: Huh. No idea what exactly happens. Next thing I'd do if I was in your place is to use `sg3-utils` and issue an SCSI READ command with `sg_read` directly, to see what happens.